# No suggestions for SdkConstants when writing intent filter in manifest file in android studio 3.5

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I am not getting any suggestions for SdkConstants when i press Ctrl+space in windows, i am trying to add new intent filter in the manifest file.

Please check the following image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GpFa.png]

Can you tell me what should i do so i can get those suggestions?

Thanks!